# spark java code to python

Tags: java, python, apache-spark, pyspark

I get a piece of mocked data,which is like:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

#columns names and each values
    columnMock = ['date','user_id','session_id','page_id','action_time','search_keyword','click_category_id','click_product_id',
                  'order_category_ids','order_product_ids','pay_category_ids','pay_product_ids','city_id']
    valsMock = [
    ('2017-03-04','1','2984','54684','2017-03-0418:02:03','dog','fjsd3','jf94fj','fk430','f4j89','rebj89','fejq9','GZ'),
    ('2017-03-04','2','294','9242','2017-03-0418:07:03','apple','fr343','jf94fj','fk430','f4j89','rebj89','fejq9','SH'),
    ('2017-03-04','1','2984','425','2017-03-0418:51:03','car','fbyt3','jf94fj','fk430','f4j89','rebj89','fejq9','BJ'),
    ('2017-03-04','2','294','92356','2017-03-0419:02:03','water','dad93','jf94fj','fk430','f4j89','rebj89','fejq9','HZ'),
    ('2017-03-04','1','2984','4014','2017-03-0419:22:03','wine','brt3','jf94fj','fk430','f4j89','rebj89','fejq9','GZ'),
    ('2017-03-04','2','294','4562','2017-03-0419:55:03','tiger','s21493','jf94fj','fk430','f4j89','rebj89','fejq9','GZ'),
    ('2017-03-04','1','2984','567','2017-03-0420:02:03','camel','rb493','jf94fj','fk430','f4j89','rebj89','fejq9','GZ'),
    ('2017-03-04','2','294','5372','2017-03-0431:02:03','glass','325g93','jf94fj','fk430','f4j89','rebj89','fejq9','GZ')
    ]


df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(valsMock, columnMock)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("sessionLog")
```

since python has no generics like in java, how can I change this function? I am thinking using map type in python to translate so that I could use groupByKey to act on `JavaPairRDD<String, Row> getSessionid2ActionRDD` which is like in Java did,but no idea how to fulfill it.

java function:

```
public static JavaPairRDD<String, Row> getSessionid2ActionRDD(JavaRDD<Row> actionRDD) {


    return actionRDD.mapPartitionsToPair(new PairFlatMapFunction<Iterator<Row>, String, Row>() {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Iterable<Tuple2<String, Row>> call(Iterator<Row> iterator)
                throws Exception {
            List<Tuple2<String, Row>> list = new ArrayList<Tuple2<String, Row>>();

            while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                Row row = iterator.next();
                list.add(new Tuple2<String, Row>(row.getString(2), row));  
            }

            return list;
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the translation of the java function to pyspark is as below

```
def createPairedTuple(partIter):
    return [(row[2], row) for row in partIter]
```

and you can call it by *converting your dataframe to rdd* and using `mapPartitions` as

```
df.rdd.mapPartitions(lambda partitionIterator: createPairedTuple(partitionIterator))
```

Or even better you can just embed the function inside `mapPartitions` as

```
df.rdd.mapPartitions(lambda partitionIterator: [(row[2], row) for row in partitionIterator])
```

I hope the answer is helpful